# might have done

Tags: modal-verbs, word-usage

The explosion **might have been** caused by a gas leak.

I think the sentence may be understood in two ways.
First: the explosion was possibily caused by a gas leak even though it did not happen.
Second: the explosion was possibily caused by a gas leak although you do not really know.

Am I right?

Comment: It has to be the first: an explosion which did not happen would not be referred to with *the*.

Comment: @StoneyB That would depend on whether the hypothetical explosion had already been mentioned. ***The plan crash might have been caused by an explosion. And the explosion might have been caused by a gas leak.*** No?

Comment: @Araucaria - But in that case you have an explosion which *may* have happened, not one which *did not* happen. Once you open a door onto a "possible world" in which there was an explosion, you have to pass through that door into that world to discuss the explosion's cause.

Comment: @StoneyB Not necessarily! For example if we know that the plane crash was caused by something different but were talking about the epistemic situation of the investigators afterwards and what they are doing or not doing we can say ***For all they know, the plan crash might have been caused by an explosion. And the explosion might have been caused by a gas leak.*** If we shot the plane down in the first place this is clearly counterfactual!

Comment: @Araucaria Ah, but in *that* case you are 'quoting' the investigators ... you have passed through another door into *their* world.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, their counterfactual world!

Comment: @Araucaria No: their world is hypothetical, not counterfactual; and once you're in their world, the explosion is no longer counterfactual either, but a hypothesis to be entertained. Just as temporal back- or fore-shift establishes a new temporal domain, modal side-shift establishes a new modal domain.

Comment: @StoneyB OK, bad example! How about this: **You know that plane crash when the other experts thought there'd been an explosion because of a bomb and we thought there had been an explosion because of a gas leak, but in the end it turned out that the plane had just crashed into a mountain? Well, it turns out that had there been an explosion it *might* have been caused by a gas leak - because all of those planes have faulty gas installations**.

Comment: @Araucaria Fersher. And in your next sentence you may refer to that hypothetical explosion again with *it*, or with a determinative *that* ... but you're still going to shy away from the definite article, as you did here. You can probably get away with the definite article if you use it; it's not ungrammatical; but it's weird.

Answer (score 1):

In the statement:

> The explosion **might have been caused** by a gas leak.

*might* used here is an auxiliary verb, part of the verb *might have been caused*. It does not affect the subject *explosion*.

So it is saying there was an explosion. There is a possibility it was caused by a gas leak, but the actual reason has not been stated yet.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct. To express hypothetical explosion, you would say

"THE gas leak might have caused AN explosion."

This means that there was a gas leak, but there wasn't an explosion. The other interpretation (that you know there was a gas leak but you don't know if there was an explosion) is highly implausible—if there had been an explosion, you'd probably know about it!

But you could remove any possible doubt by appending

", but luckily we found the leak and fixed it."